# How to install a electrical outlet box in a workbench?

Tags: electrical, workshop

I'm building a workbench for hobby electronics. I have have my basic blue prints for the bench.

I want to install outlets(3-4) along the back of the bench, embedded into the workbench.  I want to have two plugs from the workbench to my home outlets.

What cabling would I need? Can I cut up a power cable and tie it into the outlet box, and string the wire from one outlet to the other?
[image: Workbench]

Comment: Have you considered what may happen if you spill liquid on the workbench? water, coffee, paint, inflammable thinners?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My suggestion is that you consider installing a ready made plug strip across the back of the work bench. These can be purchased from many suppliers and come with an already attached heavy duty power cord that you can attach to the home outlet. Here is an example of what I am suggesting:

[image]

Let me also make another suggestion (coming from an experienced electronics person myself) that you should consider the possibility to install the plug strip up under the upper shelf of your bench instead of at the rear as you have indicated. It is much better for real usage to be able to plug things in without having to reach behind all the junk that accumulates on a work bench.

Here is a picture showing the ideal location for the plug strip. Notice how it is not hidden behind all the equipment on the bench.

[image]

Comment: I agree.  Most building code wouldn't allow for an electrical outlet to be installed on movable furniture.

Comment: +1 Also, installing outlets flush with the surface, or even at the level of the top just begs for sawdust and other debris to make its way into the sockets.

Comment: +1 on +1  Just think. Debris on an electronics workbench consists of solder, cut component leads, pieces of wire, and small electrical components. Definately NOT what you would want falling into the surface mounted outlets as proposed by the original poster.

Comment: Definitely go with the plug strip.

Comment: thanks for the advice, I've already purchased a power strip.  I'm also going to add some lighting as well.